# Writing and reading mutiple serial ports on an Arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I'm using an Arduino mega which has 4 serial ports.  On the main serial port continuously sending and receiving data between the Arduino and a computer.  The computer is doing some calculations and sending the results back to the arduino.

I'd like to see the data that the Arduino is receiving from the computer but doing a normal Serial.print()  will also send that data back to the computer, creating a big endless loop of garbage data.

Is there a way to print to the screen using on of the other serial ports.  I'm thinking that I can read/write on port1 and then send the data back to the screen using port2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't own a Mega myself, so take this with a grain of salt, but as far as i know, the three additional serial ports are **not** connected to the USB-to-serial port. Serial1-Serial3 can only be used to communicate with other devices by connecting TX(Mega) with RX(device) and vice versa.

OK, since i didn't know exactly, i had a look at the [Arduino Mega specs](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega/).
It says:

> Serial: 0 (RX) and 1 (TX); Serial 1: 19 (RX) and 18 (TX); Serial 2: 17 (RX) and 16 (TX); Serial 3: 15 (RX) and 14 (TX). Used to receive (RX) and transmit (TX) TTL serial data. Pins 0 and 1 are also connected to the corresponding pins of the FTDI USB-to-TTL Serial chip.

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: That's what I was worried about.

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  Time to look for another solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer! But let's don't give up so soon;) The serial ports are there, they are just not connected to the onboard usb. So what about a USB 2 TTL serial adaptor? Will this [MiniUSB](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/MiniUSB) work ?

Comment: Great Idea.  That reminds me that I have another Arduino uno.  I'm going to see if I can just hook up one of the serial lines to the uno and have it print out from there.